# Eliminate the parameter to find a Cartesian equation of this curve

Tags: calculus, parametric, curves

I got $y=x^\frac{7}{2}$ as the cartesian equation for the following parametric equations, but it is showing up as incorrect. Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong? Thank you!
[image: 1]

Comment: Note that $y$ can be positive, zero, or negative in the parametric form, but it can only be positive or zero in your equation. Maybe just $y^2=x^7$ instead. The graph is not the graph of a single function $y=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=t^2.t^2.t^2.t$$
$$t^2=x$$
and $$t=\pm \sqrt{x}$$
so
$$y=\pm x^{\frac{7}{2}}$$